# Dataflow template - Splunk not reading data from topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, splunk

I am using the Dataflow template that streams data from pubsub topic to splunk. I have followed the steps below from pubsub side

1. Create a topic
2. create a subscription
3. create a sink that exports log to the topic
4. give the service account permissions of publisher

For the Dataflow template

1. give topic subscription name
2. HEC endpoint
3. HEC token base64 encoded
4. create a service account that has the role/worker data, role/pubsub.reader, role/project viewer
5. Disable SSL -> true
6. vpc network
7. subnetwork name
8. create job

The worker machine spins up. The workflow is running but splunk is not pulling data from the topic. Is there anything particular I should check?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you checked Dataflow job logs for any of suspicious events occurred? Does your HEC endpoint reachable from the worker VM?

Comment: Worker logs for step "Read PubSub Events" Showing 0 messages. This is the message I see on the logs. I know the topic does have messages more than 50k unacked messages

Comment: Have you solved the current issue? If yes then it is always a good habit to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer, sharing this experience with the other Stack followers.

Comment: yes, the issue is now resloved. Thank you @mk_sta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I found after hours or wrecking my brain is that the Dataflow template requires internet access probably to download some files when it boots up. If you are behind a private vpc and internet is not accessible the please make sure to create a route with the tag "dataflow". It should then work